# How would you enable a user to reorganise/reorder a list using asp.net core 3.1 mvc with razor view without JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Given a dataset, say a table with a unique id, a name field (string) and an order field (int), in the GUI, how would you enable a user to reorganise/reorder a list (representing the table) using only asp.net core 3.1 mvc with a razor view - that is, without using JavaScript or jQuery etc?

e.g.

```
Id   Name      Order
====================
1    Fred      4
2    Simon     6
3    Bob       1
4    Emma      3
5    Anna      5
6    Carol     2
```

How would you enable the user to easily rearrange the order?

Comment: What kind of `rearrange or reorder` you want them to enable? Could you please share your desired output so that we can assist?

Comment: Not a desired output... how can a user easily change the values in a razor view for the order field? Obviously, could just have an input text box for each order index number, but that's clumsy.

Comment: So what doesn't seem clumsy to you , share with us so that we can assist you.